# Dynamic Range in an IF Statement

Tags: if-statement, dynamic, range

Im trying to run a dynamic range starting at a cell defined by another cell.

The first part of my dynamic range works, ending at a cell defined by another cell.

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True And CheckBox2.Value = True Then
  With Sheets("Summary").Range("E22")

  .FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('1600 Daily'!G$3:G$300, SMALL(IF('1600 Daily'!$F$2:$F$300=1, ROW('1600 Daily'!$F$2:$F$300)-2),ROWS(G$2:G2))),"""")"
  .AutoFill Destination:=Range("E22", Cells(Range("M4"), "E")), Type:=xlFillDefault

  End With
End If
```

I just need this formula performed across the range of cells. It seems to be this small section that does not work: `Range(Cells(Range("M4"), "E")))`

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: The language is VBA in Excel

Comment: how about setting your tags correctly so the people who know that language can find it?

Comment: Improved text and added code formatting